# Map when sorted in c++ produces huge error

Tags: c++

I am new to using maps, and when I try to sort it using the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,int> mp;
    mp[2]++;
    mp[5]++;
    mp[1]++;
    sort(mp.begin(), mp.end());
}
```

An error is thrown:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:11:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:4707:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >]’
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',21)">main.cpp:21:30</span>:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:1966:22: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator >’ and ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator >’)
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:336:5: note: candidate: template decltype ((__x.base() - __y.base())) std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:336:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:11:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:1966:22: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator >’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

What might be the problem?
I have tried changing the code in different ways, but to no avail. I dont seem to find the small mistake I have made in the code

Comment: A `map` is sorted by defintion.

Comment: `map`s are already sorted by their key values. You can't call `std::sort` on it, that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: `std::map` cares deeply about how it sorts its own elements, because it relies on it for fast searching by key. It will never allow you to change that ordering, or change an element's key.

Comment: What did you expect sorting a map to do?

Comment: @john A lot of beginners confuse `std::map<T,U>` with a `std::vector<std::pair<T,U>>` with magic lookup complexity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What might be the problem?

You don't need to sort a `std::map`, it's already sorted.

The error message (admittedly not terribly helpful) indicates that you are passing the wrong kind of iterator to `std::sort`. It needs random access iterators (see "Type requirements" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)), but `std::map` doesn't offer these (it uses bidirectional iterators). From the error message:

> error: no match for `operator-` (operand types are `std::_Rb_tree_iterator >` and `std::_Rb_tree_iterator >`)

This shows that instantiating the `std::sort` template tries to use `operator -` on the iterator returned by `mp.begin()`. Arithmetic operators exist only on random access iterators (and pointers, which satisfy the random access category).